# How to compile JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java-native-interface

I have the following code. What is the command in LINUX to compile this piece of code. gcc ThisFile.C says JNI_VERSION_1_6 undeclared..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
    return env;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM * jvm;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't complain about missing `jni.h`, have a look into this file which `JNI_VERSION_xxx` is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got myself answered. Hope this will help someone

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
gcc -o invoke -I$JAVA_HOME/include/ -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -L$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm call.c